# Breakpoint mixin compilation error

Tags: sass, gulp

I have been working on a project which involves a bit of **Sass** and **breakpoint**. I am using **gulp** to handle the workflow.

Things have been working fine until I got this compilation error which is hampering further flow. I am sharing the code as well as the error that I received on Gitbash.

***_nav.scss***

```
        a{
            color:$navForeground;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-align:center;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:10px;
            font-size:1.5em

            @include breakpoint(max-width $small){
                            font-size:1.2em;
                            span{
                                display:none;
                            }
                        }
        }//a
```

This `_nav.scss` gets compiled into `styles.css`. Below is the error that I am getting in bash.

```
Compilation failed in 1 files.

[16:32:22] { [Error:     error components/sass/style.scss (Line 25 of C:/Users/user/Desktop/responsive/components/sass/modules/_nav.scss: Invalid CSS after "  font-size:1.5em": expected ";", was "@include breakp...")
    Compilation failed in 1 files.
    ]
      message: '    error components/sass/style.scss (Line 25 of C:/Users/user/Desktop/responsive/
components/sass/modules/_nav.scss: Invalid CSS after "\t\t\tfont-size:1.5em": expected ";", was "@include breakp...")\r\nCompilation failed in 1 files.\r\n',
      fileName: 'C:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\responsive\\components\\sass\\style.scss',
      showStack: false,
      showProperties: true,
      plugin: 'gulp-compass',
      __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] } }
```

Would be really appreciative if someone could help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a semicolon after `font-size: 1.5em`:

```
font-size: 1.5em;

@include breakpoint(max-width $small) {
```